# how to center Tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I am making a presentation, using a template I found online. The problem  is that my tikzpictures are not getting in the center. I have tried `\centering`, `\begin{center}`. But that does not solve the problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[]{mcode}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{mcode}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{}

\author{}

\date{}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Fortsättning delproblem 3\dots}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    scale=1,
    >=stealth,
    point/.style = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = 1pt},
    dot/.style   = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = .2pt},
  ]

  % Punkterna R1, R2 och S
  \node (n1) at (-2,2) [point, label = below:$R_{1}$] {};
  \node (n2) at (-3,0) [point, label = {below right:$R_{2}$}] {};
  \node (n4) at (0,0)   [point, label = {below left:$S$}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\centering` requires an empty line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\centering` requires an empty line after the command to work correctly.

Please note that this should be done best in a group (although `frame` is a group already)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[]{mcode}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{mcode}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{}

\author{}

\date{}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Fortsättning delproblem 3\dots}
\begingroup
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    scale=1,
    >=stealth,
    point/.style = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = 1pt},
    dot/.style   = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = .2pt},
  ]

  % Punkterna R1, R2 och S
  \node (n1) at (-2,2) [point, label = below:$R_{1}$] {};
  \node (n2) at (-3,0) [point, label = {below right:$R_{2}$}] {};
  \node (n4) at (0,0)   [point, label = {below left:$S$}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\endgroup
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` also works, with the usual caveats (extra space may be unwanted).

Comment: @MikeRenfro: Yes, because of the vertical spacing I did not use `\begin{center}...\end{center}`